# gulp: exec multiple commands serially

Tags: node.js, gulp, imagemagick

I want to use gulp and imagemagick to batch resize images. Because I couldn't find a current gulp wrapper for imagemagick, I decided to just run imagemagick via `exec` in gulp. Like so:

```
gulp.task('images-large', function (cb) {
    exec('mogrify -path .\\images\\large -scale "1920x1080^" -gravity north -crop 1920x1080+0+0 .\\raw_images\\*.*', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log(stdout);
        console.log(stderr);
        cb(err);
    });
});

gulp.task('images-medium', function (cb) {
    exec('mogrify -path .\\images\\medium -scale "960x450^" -gravity north -crop 960x450+0+0 .\\raw_images\\*.*', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log(stdout);
        console.log(stderr);
        cb(err);
    });
});
```

Both of the above taks work fine, *when run separately*. Images of various sizes go in, come back out uniform. Now comes the problem. If I combine two similar tasks:

```
gulp.task('image', [
    'image-large',
    'image-medium'
]);
```

Then both large and medium images come out with random sizes. I'm guessing imagemagick doesn't like running multiple `mogrify` commands simultaneously. Maybe because it actually modifies the original image temporarily? It is a mystery to me.

Rather than fight with imagemagick (generally a losing proposition), I would prefer to just run my image transforms serially, large, then medium. Is there a way to run serial `exec()` commands in gulp? That is, wait for one exec to complete before running the next?

I tried something like this:

```
gulp.task('images-medium', ['images-large'], function (cb) {...});
```

Sadly, images remained randomly sized.

Plan B is to move the imagemagick stuff over to a node script and then run the node script from gulp, but that's verging into Rube Goldberg territory and I'm not sure it's my best option.

Less likely, is there something I can do to make imagemagick behave?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [run-sequence](https://github.com/OverZealous/run-sequence). I don't know anything about mogrify, but `run-sequence` will allow you to group your tasks in gulp, but still run them in sequence / serial instead of parallel.

Comment: This didn't work, sadly. Pictures still have random sizes. At a guess, I'd say the callback happens as soon as gulp is done executing and doesn't wait on imagemagick. I am happy to know `run-sequence` exists though.

Comment: Hm. When you run them separately and they work, is there still something (like `mogrify`) running in the background even when the gulp task thinks its finished? You could add some sort of timeout in between the `run-sequence` tasks to try to rule out some weird async issues going on (I wouldn't suggest keeping it in there forever, but it might help troubleshoot).

Comment: It's certainly an async issue. I can watch the files as they're created and the medium images come out interleaved with the large (no difference with run-sequence). I think I'm expecting gulp to be something its not.

Comment: Gulp should still get the job done. I think `mogrify` may be the issue here (or possibly `exec`). The trick is determining when `mogrify` is *actually* done, since `exec` seems to think it's done when it really isn't. Does `mogrify` report anything back to `stdout` which might signify completion? Is `mogrify` forking different application instances and closing the original?

Comment: `mogrify` doesn't put anything to stdout. While the script is running, there are two instances of the imagemagick process. They appear more or less simultaneously, not one after the other.

Comment: Ah. Yeah that could be a problem. Does `mogrify` close itself after spinning up the imagemagick processes?

Answer (score -1):

There is a gulp wrapper, it's called [gulp-gm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-gm). Worst case scenario, if it doesn't work, there is a [general wrapper for gm/im](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gm), much easier and cleaner than `exec()`.

Example of usage gulp-gm:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gm = require('gulp-gm');

gulp.task('default', function() {
  gulp.src('test.png')

  .pipe(gm(function(gmfile) {
    return gmfile.resize(100, 100);
  }, {
    imageMagick: true
  }))

  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```